# How to upload the image in the API request through the groovy

Tags: jmeter

In my API request, with the request payload the complete image is also getting loaded. Is there any way I can script it through JMeter using Groovy?

UI Call where I am uploading image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4wN1.png)

Main Request POST Call: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATX2m.png)

Image in the request payload: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxRAd.png)

Can it be done through groovy on JMeter.

Comment: Did you tried with Postman or Fiddler to understand the traffic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of interest, why do you want to do this in Groovy? I believe using normal [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler would be much easier, moreover you will be able to even record the request(s) using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html), this way you will get more metrics and won't need to handle the request and response.

If you still want to do this in Groovy I believe the best option would be calling relevant [Apache HttpComponents](https://hc.apache.org/) functions, example code:

```
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipartMode
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder

def imageFileName = "/path/to/your/image.png"

def post = new HttpPost("http://your-server");
def file = new File(imageFileName);
def builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
builder.addBinaryBody("file", file, ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY, imageFileName);
def entity = builder.build();
post.setEntity(entity);
def response = HttpClientBuilder.create().build().execute(post)
```

//do what you need with the response here

More information: [How to Send Groovy HTTP and HTTPS Requests](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-http-request)

Comment: Thanks , i tried with normal http request it is not working. Thought may be we can handle it with groovy script